# Reshape dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

My input dataframe sample is like this:

```
            Comment                                    Type
1      I love this product                           Generic
2      Refund order amount for my returned item      Refund     
3      Price is high                                 Merchandise
4      Product info doesn't match deal               Deal
5      I love this product                           Merchandise
6      Rude service                                  CustomerService
7      iPhone not available                          Merchandise
8      iPhone not available                          Inventory
9      Product info doesn't match deal               Price
```

A comment can fall into multiple types. I am trying to group by comment and transform type as below using Python: [Expected Output]

```
Comment                       Generic Refund Price Deal Merchandise CustomerService Inventory
I love this product             1      0      0     0       1            0             0
Refund order amount for 
my returned item                0      1      0     0       0            0             0
Price is high                   0      0      1     0       0            0             0
Product info doesn't match deal 0      0      1     1       0            0             0
Rude service                    0      0      0     0       0            1             0
iPhone not available            0      0      0     0       1            0             1
```

I tried below for grouping but I am unable to get it correct nor progress with expected output transformation:

```
df_group = inputDataframe.groupby(['comment'],as_index=False)
for key, item in df_group:
    print(key)
    print(item)
```

Please assist. Thanks!

Comment: Use `df = pd.crosstab(df.Comment, df.Type)`

Comment: Thank you jezrael. Its perfect!